# Can I add custom code to gutenberg auto save?

Tags: block-editor

I want to sync the contents of the gutenberg block-plugin instance to the cloud.. is there a way to execute a custom function when the editor auto saves?

Comment: Possibly what you're looking for [Trigger Javascript on Gutenberg (Block Editor) Save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331317/113233)

Comment: @DenIsahac thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.