Redirect to All Custom post types
I am learning plugin development.
How to redirect to All Custom post types page after insert a New Custom post type ?

Hi,
It looks like you want to you want to redirect to some URL after inserting new post types.
This can be done with the of save_posts hook with the help of that you can write logic to redirect to URL after inserting post.

@NarendraSishodiya do you speak about a javascript hook that can be used in gutenberg ?

You can listen the subscriber and trigger redirect as per the need, here is the detailed discussion. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319054/trigger-javascript-on-gutenberg-block-editor-save

Thanks @NarendraSishodiya. My code is like below.
foreach ( $fields as $field_name => $flag ) {             if ( !empty( $field = filter_input( INPUT_POST, $field_name, $flag )) ) {                                 update_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name, sanitize_text_field( $field ) );             } else {                 delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_name );             }         }.
Could you please explain more your solution ?
